# Netbeans JSF Palette

Tags: jsf, netbeans, palette

Ok, I have been trying to find answer for two days now. I created new Web Application and added JSF framework to it. But when I opened a palette I can see only few tags to be dragged and dropped. I can see HTML, HTML Forms and JSF categories with only about five tags in each. Do I have to add some library or something? Thank you for help.

Comment: No advantage of using a palette. Drop the idea of using it.

Comment: Ok, thank you for response. I´ll try to modify my question a little bit. Is there any GUI builder for Netbeans 8.0.2 (or any other self standing software) where I can use for example Primefaces components? I am just starting with JSF and I am pretty sure I would make more progress by draging-droping, rather than code writting.

Comment: I am not familiar with any decent GUI tools as I never used a "*drag and drop*" feature of any decent IDE as of now. I however, just use a nice NetBeans feature of generating entity classes and/or corresponding XML descriptors with reverse engineering files from a database so that I don't have to carefully remember each and every basic table mapping/relationship which otherwise has to be remembered carefully. In case of JSF/PrimeFaces, to start with, I would prefer using IDE's intellisense and [showcase](http://www.primefaces.org/showcase/) examples with basic demonstration.

Comment: If you are starting with JSF/Primefaces forget the nice part, the design, styling, etc, and center your brain on the understanding of the JSF life cycles, Faces Core tags, HTML tags, Expression Language, JSF scopes, Ajax... The palette only put the component on the screen, but the important is the set of attributes of each component.

Answer (score 1):

You better get rid of Netbeans JSF palette when adding components to your page. Writing directly on the page you will be more productive because you have code completion assistance. If you look at the JSF palette it is like a set of squeleton generators more than an exhaustive components set. So basically I would use, perhaps, only the JSF Data Table [From Entity] palette item.